# How to back up shsh blobs and APTicket in iOS 9.1 in order to be able to downgrade to it after update?

Tags: ipad, ios

Just got a new iPAD air 2, iOS 9.1. It says I should update it to iOS 9.3.1. 
I might be interested to jailbreak it later on, so I'd like to preserve that option for me possible.

I hear jailbreak for 9.3.1 is not available yet, and on the other hand, apple stopped signing iOS 9.1 and it is impossible to install or downgrade to iOS 9.1. I want to know how I can back up the current state with iOS 9.1, and later after I updated the iOS, when ever I wanted I could restore to the iOS 9.1.

I know that I should backup shsh blobs using Tiny Umbrella. but I cannot find the official download file in their website.
Also I don't know how to backup APTicket.

Thanks

Comment: You had two questions in here after your edit. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it seems you're mainly concerned with wanting to keep (or return to) iOS 9.1? If that's the case, then just don't update.

If, however, you're concerned with your data, such as contacts, text messages, photos, etc then updating to iOS 9.3.1 is not going to result in you losing any of this data.

If for some reason you've had to erase all data and start again with a newer version of iOS, then restoring data from a backup with an older iOS version works fine, so long as it is a backup from the same device.

So I guess what I'm saying is that as long as you have done a backup prior to updating iOS, then you will have no reason to ever go back to iOS 9.1. Even if you lost all your data, you'd be able to restore the data from your backup.

Also, I want to add there are a lot of reasons why you should update to the latest iOS version as Apple has recently resolved a number of serious (albeit rare) issues that could have bricked your device.

Hope this helps. Any questions, just ask.

Comment: I'd have to disagree on one of your points regarding device backups. I've churned through at least a few iPhones (technically being "different devices") and have never had a problem restoring a backup from a previous iPhone to a newer one.

Comment: Also, iOS 9.1 is currently the last iOS version to have a jailbreak publicly available. I'd suggest staying on it for now if jailbreaking may be appealing, otherwise feel free to update.

Comment: @Brian Totally agree with the backups from earlier devices to newer ones. I have done this too, many times. I guess I was just being extra cautious with regard the OP's exact scenario. Thanks though for clarifying this point.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, that's exactly my concern. I'm new to iOS, but in case I wanted to jailbreak later on, I'd like to have that option possible. So from what I understood, there is absolutely no way to downgrade iOS after it is updated? right?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you'd want to jailbreak. It used to be something that provided some limited advantages for some users, but nowadays the risks far outweigh any advantages. Most of the reasons people used to jailbreak their iOS devices are now features built into iOS. That said though, I suppose there may be some future functionality offered via a jailbroken device that won't be available to stock standard users, but certainly for some time the risks have outweighed the advantages.